# findding a key in an object in node.js

Tags: json, node.js

i have a lookup-table of JSON, i want to search for a specific key in that lookup-table; which could return me the complete object of the match.
Is it possible without any loop or with any built-in liberary.

Answer (score 0):

its JSON, a straight look up for the key.?

```js
var obj = { 'foo' : 'bar', 'fez' : [1,2,3], 'fizz' : { 'baz': true} }; 

console.log( "'foo' is accessed like " +  obj.foo + " -or- " + obj['foo'] )

var fw_table = {"FW_1":{ "tn":"sn_201", "cf": "06.57", "ci": "A1", "di":"048"}, "FW_2":{ "tn":"sn_202", "cf": "06.57", "ci": "A2", "di":"045"}};


function search(fwObj, key, val){
   var topKey = Object.keys(fwObj).find((e)=>{ return(fwObj[e][key] === val ) });
   console.log(topKey);
   return fwObj[topKey]; 
}

console.log("Find cf:'06.57' : ", search(fw_table, "cf","06.57") );
console.log("Find di:'045' : ", search(fw_table, "di","045") );
```